# Is it possible to de-serialize a stream collection directly into a dictionary? instead of using ToDictionary

Tags: c#, .net-core, stream, deserialization

I'm having this simple collection of stocks and prices:

```
[
    { "name": "AABA", "price": 60.6808},
    { "name": "AAL", "price": 33.3216}
]
```

Stock class:

```
public class Stock
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to de-serial the stream directly into IDictinary where the key is the `Name` and the value is the `Stock` (for performance reason), I was only able to do so with de-serializing the stream into a `IEnumerable<Stock>` and then convert it Dictionary with:

```
using (stream)
{
    IDictinary<string, Stock> = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
            .DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Stock>>(stream.BaseStream, 
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false }, 
            ct); 
}
```

The only way I was able to achieve this was by adding the `ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => new Stock() { Name = x.Name, Price = x.Price })` at the end.

**Is it possible to read the stream directly as a dictionary?**

like:

```
    IDictinary<string, Stock> = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
            .DeserializeAsync<IDictinary<string, Stock>>(stream.BaseStream, 
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false }, 
            ct);
```

Comment: `ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x)` would at least let you reuse the existing `Stock` objects rather than constructing new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not really the right shape for a dictionary. What you're already doing is IMO the right way to do this. You *could* try and write a custom deserialized to avoid a step, but that is a *lot* of work, and a lot of opportunities to introduce bugs, compared to what you already have that will work correctly.